# How to solve a system of coupled complex equations?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Given two equations `x = a/(b - I (2 c y - m));` and     `y = (I  c x^2)/(p + I q);` where $a,b,c,m,p,q$ are all real, how to solve for $x$ or $y$?

I tried substituting $y$ from the second equation into the first one and then solving using `Solve` as:

```
Solve[x == a/(b - I (2 c ((I  c x^2)/(p + I q)) - m)), x]
```

However, it shows that `Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded`.

Comment: The error likely means that you previously assigned something to x or y and that is being kept in cache to speed things up, but that is interfering with your `Solve`. Try in a fresh new notebook `Reduce[{x==a/(b-I(2 c y-m)),y==(I c x^2)/(p+I q)},{x,y}]` and see that you have one sort of trivial solution and three solutions from a cubic equation. To see the ugly details of that you can use `ToRadicals[...the solution...]` but that isn't pretty and `Simplify` doesn't help. You can try including `Element[a|b|c|m|p|q,Reals]`  in `Reduce` but that doesn't seem to help a lot. Hope you can use this.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, in a fresh notebook, it shows "a/(b-I\(-m+(2 I a^2 c^2)/(Plus[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>]^2))) is not a valid variable" .

Comment: As you suggested I pasted Reduce[{x == a/(b - I (2 c y - m)), y == (I c x^2)/(p + I q)}, {x, y}]

Comment: Ah, now it works after I Quit[ ] the evaluation. Thanks. But as you rightly pointed out, the solution doesn't simplify to a nice form.